# Google.GoogleApiException: 'Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError ... does not have storage.objects.list access to the Google

Tags: c#, google-cloud-platform

I tried this code at https://gist.github.com/henrikj242/af06ac41fc9554dab387c0bb3a994f85
but at line `foreach (var obj in storageClient.ListObjects(bucketName, ""))`

> Google.GoogleApiException: 'Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError ... does
> not have storage.objects.list access to the Google

This means I pass in invalid bucketName?

Comment: Not an *invalid* bucket name, but one that the credential you're using doesn't have access to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it was mentioned in comments by *@Jon Skeet*, this issue related to [Cloud IAM](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/overview) and [Cloud Storage roles](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#cloud-storage-roles). Accordingly to the error message, your service account doesn't have required permissions like `storage.objects.list`.

**To solve this issue** you can create a new service account, grant roles of `storage.admin` and `storage.object.admin`, create a new key and use it.

In addition, have a look at the documentation [Understanding roles](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles) and [Understanding service accounts](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-service-accounts).

Answer (score 1):

This is not properly an issue, you have to grant roles `storage.admin` (You can use Storage Admin) and `storage.object.admin` (Storage Object Admin) but **you have to wait several hours to be able to use the permissions related to your service account.**

[image]

[Enforce least privilege with role recommendations](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/recommender-overview)